# Gravity Falls conspiracies and secrets

Tags: discussion

There are so many hidden things in Gravity Falls series, I don't think it's possible to ask valid questions for a Q&A site, but still I'd like to know more about them. Is it okay to ask for a list of websites which have a lot of information regarding hidden messages and such on this site?

Usually asking for a list of sites regarding a certain subject is frowned upon on SE sites, but in this case it's about opinion based and officially unconfirmed theories mostly anyway, so I'm not sure if it's the same.

Comment: Asking for list of site appears off-topic. But i think question regarding hidden messages of a show is always on-topic. Can you provide which kind of question you want to ask.

Answer (score 4):

Asking for a list is a close/nuke/destroy/obliterate.

The reason is because there is no possible limit to the answers and all it does is make the site a signpost to other sites and such and doesn't exactly improve the overall *content* of the site.

This is where it gets tricky.

One could argue *analysis* questions do the same but, it is the actual analysis with long explanations and sources from the work being analyzed that make it worthwhile content.

For instance, if you were to ask for a list of sites that do analysis on *Gravity Falls*.  It would get immediately closed by either a mod or by the users of the site.

However if you were to ask (bear in mind I've NEVER seen *Gravity Falls*) for example:

"Why choose the title Gravity Falls?"

That would be a (possibly) interesting piece of analysis that could produce a multitude of answers each one (hopefully) producing reasoning and logic using examples from the series to back up their claims.  Thus adding to the content of the site in a positive way.

---

My suggestion to you is, because this is meta, edit your question with some examples of questions you want to ask about the series and we can help you shape them into great questions for the site.

Another option is pop into the [**Movies Chat**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888/the-screening-room) we would love to help you shape your questions into interesting analysis pieces.